# How to click item in one list and populate the another one?

Tags: react-redux

I'm new in React-Redux and thinking how to solve the following - I have 2 lists of items, left one and right tone. When I click to some items in left list, the right list should be populated with items from database based on some id/key of item I've selected in left list.

It sounds fairly easy, but how to implement it in React-Redux?

Of course, I'm not asking for full functional solution, but I haven't found something similar on internet. If you know some internet resource that refers to this or you can push me to right direction, I'll be thankful.

Comment: Do both lists share a parent? And do you have to do this via a store? I can suggest a non store way if they share a parent container

Comment: I should use Redux's store.

Comment: Regarding common parent for both lists I have no idea what is better because I said I was new in React-Redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `onChange` handler on first element (if it's select) or `onClick` if it's not, and pass some data-id attribute which is the one you will use to filter for second item.

In the onChange/onClick method, `dispatch` action (with that ID) which will fetch content from the database according to the ID and save it to the `store`. Second item should listen to the same store, and populate from let's say, `state.secondItem`.

It's not complicated, but tends to have a few of steps involed, especially using Redux.